# What does the command afplay --leaks do?

Tags: command-line, big-sur

What does the command afplay --leaks do?

The man page states that it performs leak analyzes.
What are leak analyzes, please? When I ran this command with an audio file, no event occurred.

Comment: `--leaks` analyzes memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

`--leaks` analyzes memory leaks. Running `strings /usr/bin/afplay` strongly indicates that

```
leaks -nocontext %d | tee /tmp/leaks_P%d.log
x=`cat /tmp/leaks_P%d.log |grep -i Leak: | wc -l`
exit $x
```

is actually run for this. `man leaks` will give a lot of additional details about what that command does.